# Input date don't work on safari

Tags: javascript, html

Date calendar doesn't work on safari browser but work correctly on other browser.

This is my code for the input date :

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Date de :</label>
    <input type="date" required class="form-control" ng-model="date_debutOP">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please follow the guidance in the following link on how to ask a question on this forum. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Specifically, what doesn't work, what have you tried and what is the desired behavior.

Comment: Here is the related WebKit bug:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119175

Answer (score 1):

The input-type Date is n newer one which isn´t supported on each browser. It´s just a field-validation and in some browsers there is a datepicker.
First only Chrome and now Firefox/..., too.

You could use this instead and it´s very simple:
[JavaScript Datepicker](http://tutorialvilla.com/how/how-to-solve-the-problem-of-html-date-picker)

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date),

> input[type=date] is recognized but there is no UI.

Meaning, the browser doesn't have a calendar-like display for such input controls.

You could also refer to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20date) to check for compatibility for such features.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a bit late, but better late then never ;-)
This works for me:

Add this to your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_support_html5_fallback', '__return_true' );
```

Then add this to your custom css:

```
div#ui-datepicker-div { z-index:1000!important; }
```

The inputfield still looks empty, but when you click on it, it will open the datepicker.